# Extracting ByteString from IO context?

Tags: haskell, io, monads, bytestring

I have a function that makes a http request, I need to access the returned byte string. However, the monadic function I have doesn't seem to be able to return the  ByteString separated from its IO.

See below:

```
executeRequest :: IO LAZ.ByteString
executeRequest = do
   response <- simpleHttp "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
   return (response)

html = executeRequest

extractBytesFromIO :: IO LAZ.ByteString -> LAZ.ByteString
extractBytesFromIO html = do
    bytes <- html
    bytes
```

The above won't compile, with an error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘LAZ.ByteString’ with actual type ‘IO b0’
```

I need to bring the ByteString out of the local scope of the function, so the below will not work:

```
html - executeRequest

extractBytesFromIO :: IO LAZ.ByteString
extractBytesFromIO = do
   bytes <- html
   let doStuff = //do stuff with bytes
   html
```

Any suggestions on how extractBytesFromIO can return the ByteString without the IO context?

Comment: If this were possible then we wouldn't need an `IO` monad in the first place.

Comment: You can "bring it out of the local scope of the function," it's just that the function you bring it into has to also be in the IO monad.